# troubles in in ensemble learning in R

Tags: r, ensemble-learning

I use ensemble learning for my classification task, but i got the error.

i use `library("ensembleR")`

```
acc1=read.xlsx("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/buyning.xlsx")
index <- sample(1:nrow(acc1),round(0.75*nrow(acc1)))
train <- acc1[index,]
test <- acc1[-index,]
preds <- ensemble(train,test,'id',c('treebag','rpart'),'rpart')

Error in train.default(training[, predictors], training[, outcomeName],  : 
  Stopping

Something is wrong; all the RMSE metric values are missing:
      RMSE        Rsquared  
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :1     NA's   :1
```

what is it? Here the mydata.
[acc1](https://www.sendspace.com/file/mdrvt6)
    Also i used caretEnsemble"

```
library("caretEnsemble")
models <- caretList(train,test, methodList=c("glm", "lm"))
```

and also i got errors

```
Error: nrow(x) == n is not TRUE
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In trControlCheck(x = trControl, y = target) :
  trControl$savePredictions not 'all' or 'final'.  Setting to 'final' so we can ensemble the models.
```

last my attempt was library("classyfire")

```
   acco=read.xlsx("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/buyning.xlsx")
iClass <- acco[,1]
idata  <- acco[,-1]

ens <- cfBuild(inputData = idata, inputClass = iClass, bootNum = 100,
               ensNum = 100, parallel = TRUE, cpus = 4, type = "SOCK")
```

but i got the error

```
Error in .initCheck(inputData, inputClass, bootNum, ensNum, parallel,  : 
  Argument "inputData" must contain numeric values.
```

Please help me, why all methods don't work?

Comment: A good starting point would be to look at your actual data. What does it look like?

Comment: i gave my data(https://www.sendspace.com/file/mdrvt6) , depended var is id (1-good,0-bad)